# Response struct does not like CodingKeys

Tags: swift, swift5

I have this struct used to decode a JSON coming from the server:

```
struct AdminResponse: Codable {
  let Status: Int?
  let SuperUsers: [SuperUser]?
  let Message: String?
}

struct SuperUser: Codable {
  let name:String?
  let id:String?
}
```

This works perfectly. I am able to decode the JSON.

But I don't like these properties with the first uppercase, then I do

```
struct AdminResponse: Codable {
  let Status: Int?
  let SuperUsers: [SuperUser]?
  let Message: String?
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case status = "Status"
    case superUsers = "SuperUsers"
    case message = "Message"
  }
}

struct SuperUser: Codable {
  let name:String?
  let id:String?

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "name"
    case id = "id"
  }
}
```

> Error: Type AdminResponse does not conforme to protocol Decodable.

Why???

Comment: Name the var of `AdminResponse` starting with a lowercase (ie, the same name of the cases of `CodingKeys`). That's your issue.

Comment: From the doc: `The names of the enumeration cases should match the names you've given to the corresponding properties in your type.` from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types):

> Codable types can declare a special nested enumeration named
> CodingKeys that conforms to the CodingKey protocol. When this
> enumeration is present, its cases serve as the authoritative list of
> properties that must be included when instances of a codable type are
> encoded or decoded. **The names of the enumeration cases should match
> the names you've given to the corresponding properties in your type.**

In other words:

```
struct CodableStruct: Codable {
  let myPropertyName: SomeCodableType
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case myPropertyName = "WhateverIsMatchingInRealityTheJSON"
  }
}
```

And it's mandatory that `myPropertyName` be the name of the var of `CodableStruct` AND the name of the `case` of the `CodingKeys`.

In your case, since it's recommended to name the var starting with a lowercase, I'll go that way:

```
struct AdminResponse: Codable {
  let status: Int?
  let superUsers: [SuperUser]?
  let message: String?
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case status = "Status"
    case superUsers = "SuperUsers"
    case message = "Message"
  }
}
```